# Use JCE EllipticCurve Class with Montgomery Curves

Tags: java, cryptography, jce, elliptic-curve

I'm using Java Cryptography Extension to do Elliptic Curve Cryptography. The choosen curves I came up with (based on http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) are all Montgomery equations and i didn't find any way to represent/process them in JCE. So is there a way to do ECC with Montgomery equations in JCE?

I'm using Java 7 and Bouncy Castle as JCE Provider.

Here's the actual code I'm dealing with:

```
import java.security.spec.ECFieldFp;
import java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECPoint;
import java.security.spec.EllipticCurve;

        EllipticCurve curve = new EllipticCurve(
                new ECFieldFp(prime), a, b);
        ECParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECParameterSpec(
                curve,
                basePoint,
                basePointOrder,
                coFactor);
        KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
        g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
        pair = g.generateKeyPair();
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve gives formulas to convert to Weierstrass form.

Comment: @Henry: I tried this already with curve Curve25519 but came up with negative coefficients which were not accepted by the EllipticCurve class. Nevertheless, I'm not sure if it is wise to use such an conversion because I'm to less into the mathematics of ECC to be clear about the security repercussions of such an conversion.

Comment: Pretty much the whole point of "safe curves" is that it's easier to write good implementations for it. By converting to weierstrass you lose that advantage.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Although that won't matter much if you just want compatibility with other software, I guess.